# How to add an existing cmake project to the Visual Studio Solution

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, visual-studio-2017, solution

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and I have a solution consisting of several projects mainly in C++. Now I want to add an existing C++ project which using CMake for building to my solution in visual studio and build it along with other projects in solution. Is it possible to do that? FYI, I can build the cmake project separately in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

For modern C++ projects, it is most definitely not recommended to use vs project(.sln) to build the project. The best practice is to convert the existing vs project into a cmake project.

This is complicated for huge projects, so I'll give a few ways to solve the current problem.

1. If the dependent project is a commonly used open source library, try using `vcpkg`. This is the best method. You only need a dozen minutes to understand it briefly.
2. If it is a private library and its cmake file is good.

```
cd dependent
cmake -S . -B build
cmake --build build --config Release
cmake --install build --prefix install
```

In the settings of the vs project,
include path add `dependent/install/include`,
lib path add `dependent/install/lib`

3. Resolve dependencies using project references

```
cd dependent
cmake -S . -B build -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"
```

In the vs solution view, right click on the solution and add existing project, select the .vcxproj project in the `dependent/build/dependent` directory.

Refer to the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-and-remove-project-dependencies?view=vs-2022) to continue completing your project references.

Comment: *The best practice is to convert the existing vs project into a cmake project.* According to whom?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @adrian-mole According to Microsoft's official documentation, using Visual Studio IDE to build cross-platform projects without using .sln (vs solution project) is the only correct solution. You can still edit, compile and run the project like a .sln project, the only difference is that you need to modify the project configuration in cmakelists.txt. You can view more information from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmake-projects-in-visual-studio?view=msvc-170

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the best solution for adding CMake projects to a Visual Studio project is to use [vcpkg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcpkg/).

It's a C/C++ language package manager that integrates nicely with Visual Studio and CMake.

- https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg#quick-start-windows
- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/vcpkg-is-now-included-with-visual-studio/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcpkg/users/buildsystems/msbuild-integration
- [How to use vcpkg installed packages in Visual Studio in reality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59865669/how-to-use-vcpkg-installed-packages-in-visual-studio-in-reality)