# How to use vcpkg installed packages in Visual Studio in reality?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vcpkg

It is written [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg)

> In Visual Studio, you can create a New Project (or open an existing
>   one). All installed libraries are immediately ready to be #include'd
>   and used in your project without additional configuration.

Which is not true in reality. If I do `New Project` and create either Console or CMake application from scratch and have some CGAL includes (since I have CGAL installed in `vgpkg`) I am (obviously) getting error messages, saying that `CGAL` includes are not found.

How to fix? May be put path to vcpkg somewhere in Visual Studio or something?

---

`vcpkg integrate install` also doesn't help.

```
D:\dev\vcpkg>vcpkg integrate install
Applied user-wide integration for this vcpkg root.

All MSBuild C++ projects can now #include any installed libraries.
Linking will be handled automatically.
Installing new libraries will make them instantly available.

CMake projects should use: "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=D:/dev/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"
```

It claimed it will work, but it doesn't

[image]

And it is obviously, because there is not magic in the world.

So, what else from "without additional configuration" I forgot?

Comment: Did you run `vcpkg integrate install`?

Comment: I don't remember. Anyway it IS SOME configuration required :)

Comment: It's written in the docs. You clone vcpkg, run the build script, and do a one-time `vcpkg integrate install`. Literally at the top of the readme file you linked.

Comment: [https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/docs/users/integration.md#integrate](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/docs/users/integration.md#integrate)

Comment: "*what else from "without additional configuration" I forgot?*" How can we know? We're not at your computer, and we didn't follow the instructions at your computer, so we can't know what steps you missed.

Comment: Did you actually build the project? Intellisense isn't always reliable.

Comment: @Timo it doesn't work; and I would say it can't work, please, read the statement:  to all VS2015 and VS2017 MSBuild projects. Should it scan my several terabytes HDD to find these projects first?

Comment: @NicolBolas just say what is wrong with the statement, that configuration is not required. Fix it.

Comment: It looks like you are using CMake for your project. The instructions for CMake are different. With CMake I use the toolchain file and configure using CMake-gui.

Comment: That's not how it works. There are default paths that are inherited by each project IIRC. There is no magic scanning happening. Also does your triplet match the installed libraries?

Comment: Also , your console output says `CMake projects should use: "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=D:/dev/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"`

Comment: @Timo what is "triplet"? I can run CGAL examples with building SLN files with `cmake-gui`. Here I am asking, how to get "you can create a New Project (or open an existing one). All installed libraries are immediately ready to be #include'd and used in your project without additional configuration" in reality?

Comment: @Timo I can set toolchain it `cmake-gui`, yes. I am asking about zero configuration of creating new projects in VS.

Comment: [https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/docs/users/triplets.md](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/docs/users/triplets.md)

Comment: Then use a Visual Studio project format instead of cmake if you are not willing to copy & paste one line of code.

Comment: @drescherjm so "no additional configuration" means actualy "read tons of manuals and try to figure out what to configure actually", it's okay

Comment: Its no configuration for Visual Studio projects. For CMake based projects I believe you have to tell CMake about the toolchain file.

Comment: It means you don't need to do anything if you use a vcproj project format. If you use cmake you have the burden of pasting one line of code in your .cmake file.

Comment: @drescherjm it doesn't work with "no configuration" for VS project too. How would it? It shoudl have paths to libraries and includes in property pages. Who would put it there?

Comment: @Timo vsproj doesn't work either; why would it? there is no magic; somebody should put settings into project properties, which was not done of course.

Comment: @Dims: "*just say what is wrong with the statement*" I did say what's wrong with your statement: that you can't expect people to remotely fix a problem local to your machine. I don't have anything to say about the statement from the documentation.

Comment: I wish it. But it will not be "no additional configuration". I was just surprised, reading this. Fortunately, this is not true.

Comment: @NicolBolas my machine is ok :) zero configuration is not ok :)

Comment: Should I run `vcpkg integrate install` on macOS/Linux also or that's a Visual Studio thing?

Answer (score 3):

It was a "triplet" problem (x86 was set instead of x64). Sorry for troubles, guys :)

Comment: x86 is the default. There is an issue asking to change the default to 64 bit however no action has been taken: [https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/1254](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/1254)

Comment: could you elaborate on this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue and I have no idea what this means in the slightest.